# Initialize base class without copy constructor from derived class constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

I need to derive from a class `Tool`, as I must decorate that class with another interface `IToolWrapper`. Unfortunately, the `Tool` class does not provide a copy constructor, which is why I think one cannot write the contructor of the `DerivedTool` like

```
public DerivedTool(String filename) : base(createToolFromFile(filename)) {
    //...
}
```

Although I was quite sure it wouldn't work I tried the following:

```
public sealed class DerivedTool : Tool, IToolWrapper {

    static bool createToolFromFile(ref Tool tool, String filename) {
        tool.Dispose();
        tool = null;
        try {
            tool = LoadFromFile(filename) as Tool;
        } catch ( Exception ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public DerivedTool(String filename) : base() {
        Tool tool = (Tool)this;
        if ( !createToolBlockFromFile(ref tool, filename) ) throw new Exception("Tool could not be loaded!");
    }

}
```

In the debugger, I see that `tool` as I local variable to the constructor is modified as required (b/c the catch case isn't entered), but the base part of `DerivedTool` (i.e. the `Tool`) is not affected.
How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: We can't know how the `CogToolBlock` class works, better than you, unless we know more about it.

Comment: Why don't you create another class that takes a Tool instance in the constructor and implements the interface by forwarding the actions to the provided Tool-instance? Do you need to use the new class as a substitute for an out-of-the-box Tool, e.g. hand it to methods that take a Tool as a parameter?

Comment: @Matz: the question is not really clear... can you please explain a little in detail and crisp so that we can help you out with the perfect solution.

Comment: My intention was to (i) add `IToolWrapper` methods to `Tool` and (ii) at the same time be able to use `DerivedTool` in place of  `Tool`. Directly inheriting seems not possible due to the lack of a copy-constructor in `Tool`. Farzan's solution works however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use combination of a private variable and implicit/explicit operator as like below:

```
public sealed class DerivedTool : IToolWrapper {
    private Tool _tool;

    public DerivedTool(String filename) : base() {
        _tool = LoadFromFile(filename) as Tool;
    }

    public static implicit operator Tool(DerivedTool dt)
    {
        return dt._tool;
    }
}
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable and works - in my case. Thanks.